# Java convert string into url title characters only

Tags: java, android

I'm developing an android app, I need to construct an url form some strings in an Ad object.

So, the header has to be converted into a correct url string, in Codeigniter I have the function called:

```
url_title($str, $separator = '-', $lowercase = FALSE)
```

But how I do this in android?

My actual string:

```
"https://www.bachecubano.com" + category + "/" + my_custom_function(header) + "/" + ad_id;
```

where `my_custom_function(header)` is the desired function which removes spaces, remove special characters, etc.

The `query = URLEncoder.encode(text, "utf-8");` answer won't solve my problem, it change space for `+`, I need spaces changed to `-`

Actual string:

```
https://www.bachecubano.com/celulares/QUEREMOS+Q+TENGA+UN+BUEN+TELEFONO+Y+LO+ADQUIERA+MAS+BARATO/674337
```

Desired String:

```
https://www.bachecubano.com/celulares/QUEREMOS-Q-TENGA-UN-BUEN-TELEFONO-Y-LO-ADQUIERA-MAS-BARATO/674337
```

In other words, I need this in Java (PHP function)

```
return preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: I assume that you really do have a `"` at the beginning of `"https` in your code.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot it.

Comment: No problem! I just wanted to be doubly sure I did not edit away the source of the problem. It could have been very frustrating to an asker with less experience than I presume you have.

Comment: URLEncoder is the answer, check the duplicate